# Обработать возможные ошибки пользовательского ввода ( try,catch и thow ) При нахождении факториала числа

Tags: java

Нужно вычислить и отобразить факториал числа, заданного в командной строке. Обработать возможные ошибки пользовательского ввода при помощи try, catch и throw.
У меня получилось лишь найти факторил числа без операторов try, catch и throw:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       int n;
        do {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.print("Введите факториал натурально числа n : ");
              n = scan.nextInt();
               int result = 1;
                for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
                  result *= i;
                  System.out.println(result);
                if (n == 0 || n == 1)
                 System.out.println(result);
             if(n < 0)
             System.out.println("Вы ввели отрицательный факториал!");
        } while (n < 0);{System.out.println("Конец");}
    }
}
```

Жду помощи!

Comment: Почитайте про исключения, помогите себе сами

Comment: Извините, но я бы не обращался сюда за помощью если бы мог помочь себе сам, читал и пытался, но не получается ничего.

Comment: И в чем проблема написать throw вместо вывода сообщения об отрицательном вводе, например?

Comment: Ну напишите если вам не трудно

Comment: Тут как-то не принято решать за других их задачи, если они сами ничего для их решения не сделали...

Comment: Но я же сделал все что мог, код написал, ппц, ЧСВ'ешные тут походу все

Comment: Вы учитесь - вот и учитесь. Толку от написания кода за вас будет ноль. Если вам это программирование не нужно - идите к фрилансерам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = 0;
while (true) {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите факториал натурально числа n : ");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Некорректный ввод!");
    }
}
do {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) result *= i;
    System.out.println(result);
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) System.out.println(result);
    if (n < 0) System.out.println("Вы ввели отрицательный факториал!");
} while (n < 0);
System.out.println("Конец");
```

Если отделить пользовательский ввод от вычислений , то все проще.
Но в любом случае ваш способ плохой.
Код простейшего алгоритма написан достаточно запутано. Для значения факториала использован int. Попробуйте посчитать факториал 20 и посмотрите, что получится и это всего лишь 20. Я бы еще понял long, но в этом случае даже он вас не спасет. Попробуйте использовать biginteger. А еще попробуйте написать это с помощью рекурсии, но это для общего развития, а не для реальной жизни. Рекурсия при вычислении факториала на больших значениях задумается надолго, а может и исключение бросить. Разберитесь с тем, что я написал, это уже будет довольно неплохо. Удачи